# Calculate Gas Mileage

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to track my gas mileage ("MPG") from tank to tank.

Here is my `Stops` table:

```
stopID, int(11) auto_increment
vendorID, int(11)
vehicleID, int(11)
mileage, int(11)
date, date
gallons, float
cost, float
remarks, varchar(32)
```

Here is my `Vendors` table:

```
vendorID, int(11) auto_increment
vendor, varchar(32)
street, varchar(32)
city, varchar(32)
state, varchar(2)
zip, varchar(5)
```

Here is my `Vehicles` table:

```
vehicleID, int(11) auto_increment
year, year(4)
make, varchar(16)
model, varchar(16)
type, varchar(16)
vin, varchar(32)
```

So far I'm using the following query (it works), to which I'd like to add a calculated `MPG` column:

```
SELECT v.vendorID, 
       v.vendor,  
       v.city,  
       v.state,  
       FORMAT(s.mileage , 0 ) Miles ,  
       DATE_FORMAT(s.date , '%m/%d/%y' )  Date ,  
       FORMAT(s.gallons , 3 ) Gal ,  
       FORMAT(s.cost , 2 ) Cost ,  
       FORMAT(s.cost /s.gallons , 3 ) Rate 
FROM Stops s 
INNER JOIN Vendors v  
       ON s.vendorID =v.vendorID  
       AND s.remarks ='Fuel'  
       AND s.vehicleID =2  
       AND s.date >= '2014-07-01'
ORDER BY `Date`  DESC
```

Here is a typical output from the existing query (without MPG column):

```
vendorID    vendor  city        state   Miles   Date        Gal     Cost    Rate    (MPG)
14          Sunoco  Arnold      MD      122,104 07/18/14    3.741   15.22   4.068
14          Sunoco  Arnold      MD      121,936 07/16/14    3.633   14.89   4.099
14          Sunoco  Arnold      MD      121,770 07/14/14    3.276   13.43   4.100
29          BP      Washington  DC      121,620 07/11/14    3.635   15.26   4.198
```

I tried looking for answers already (both Stack Overflow and in the mySQL documentation), but they all seem to depend on having consecutive ID values, or having a particular column sorted in a certain way. Since I have multiple vehicles and multiple stops (not just for `remarks` = 'Fuel'), those solutions don't work. Please feel free to ask any questions to clarify, and I'll update my question as needed to provide additional info.

Comment: Note that it's stunningly unlikely that you want to store floats as opposed to decimals. And while it's great to see what you've attempted, it's probably no less useful to provide proper DDLs (sqlfiddle's good for that) together with the desired result set.

Comment: Do you want to get a `MPG` column for each vehicle? I'm having trouble understanding what `MPG` means in relation to  `stops` and `vendors`.

Comment: I'll select only one vehicle for each query. In this example, I queried on vehicle = 2.

Comment: MPG would be calculated by 1) subtracting the mileage of one stop from the previous stop, and then 2) dividing the result by gallons. As an example, 122104 - 121936 = 168 miles; 168 miles / 3.741 gallons = 44.9 miles per gallon (MPG). Again, since the table contains stops from more than one vehicle and for multiple reasons, the query must calculate from records for only the selected vehicle (in this case, vehicleID = 2 and remarks = 'Fuel').

Comment: @Strawberry - I didn't know any better so I just went with float ... but I will try to use the correct data type when I update the table. Thanks for the hint on using sqlfiddle!

Comment: @aa333 - Stops is the table that contains the necessary data; Vendors is only there so I can tell where I stopped when viewing the query results.

Comment: If the `MPG` is calculated using data from 2 rows of `Stops`, you would either need a reference to the next/previous stop or an ordering to work it out correctly, having consecutive ID values is just a way to enforce that order.

Comment: I know this is a old post, but for future reference, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626828/calculate-mileage-of-vehicles-by-subtracting-from-vehicle-readings/45820972#45820972

Answer (score 1):

Following a suggestion I made in the question comments, if you add a self reference column to `Stops` the solution would be a lot easier without the need for maintaining any order:

`Stops` table would be:

`stopID, int(11) auto_increment
vendorID, int(11)
vehicleID, int(11)
mileage, int(11)
date, date
gallons, float
cost, float
remarks, varchar(32)
previous_stopID int(11)`

And the query to get `MPG` would be:

`SELECT cur.stopID, cur.vendorID, (cur.mileage-prev.mileage)/cur.gallons as MPG
    FROM Stops cur INNER JOIN Stops prev
    WHERE cur.prev_StopID = prev.stopID`

You could then join/merge this with `Vendors` to get any additional columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use a self join.  This answer will show you the general idea, but it's untested and may have errors.

```
select (ThisStop.mileage - PreviousStop.mileage) / ThisStop.gallons mpg
from stops.ThisStop join stops.PreviousStop on ThisStop.vehicleId = PreviousStop.vehicleId
where PreviousStop.date = 
(select max(date) from stops
where vehicleId = ThisStop.vehicleId
and date < ThisStop.date)
```

If you want to identify the vendor, get it from PreviousStop.