# Calculate Mileage of Vehicles by Subtracting from Vehicle Readings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which vehicle mileage i.e the mileage of the vehicle is stored on a regular basis.

```
The table:
----------
ID (primary key)
Vehicle_id 
date_of_reading (datetime)
Mileage
```

By the end of the month i want to pick the Last reading of the Past Month and subtract it from the Last Reading of this Month to get the Total Km that all the vehicles have traveled.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34b8b

**Structure of the Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_readings` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `km_driven` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `dt_of_reading` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dt_of_entry` datetime NOT NULL,
  `entry_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`),  CONSTRAINT `tbl_readings_ibfk_1`     FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `table_vehicle_info` (`id`) ON DELETE     CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=394     DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Almost every day vehicle Meter readings are posted in this table. And by the end of the month these readings are used to calculate the number of KM the vehicles are driven. The no of Km have to be calculated by taking the Last Reading of the previous month and subtracting it from  the last reading of the current Month.

I hope it is much clearer now. I realize my question was way too ambiguous.

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables.

Comment: @jpw because it's way easier to read than a wall of text, less ambiguous than natural language and easier to experiment with if you are so inclined :)

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The wording is ambiguous.

Comment: @jpw has raised a good point about (last, last) and (first, last). As far as we know, June 2015 has a last reading on June 24th. Now you are into July 2015 and first reading is July 10. Clean up the question please

Comment: Thanks @DrewPierce, I answered having misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Huge fat disclaimer:** This comes with *no* warranty, but *if* I have understood your problem *and* I'm not wrong somewhere, consider the following.

Your table being

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (`id` INTEGER, `date` DATE, `mileage` INT);
```

One possible way is to first create a view with the date of last month's latest reading (which you can turn into another nested `SELECT` if you are so inclined):

```
CREATE VIEW `past_month_readings` 
AS (SELECT `id`, 
    max(`date`) AS `latestreading`
    FROM `foo` 
    WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW())-1 
    GROUP BY `id`);
```

Followed by

```
SELECT `currentmileages`.`id`, `currentmileage`-`previousmileage` FROM 
 (SELECT `foo`.`id`, `mileage` AS `currentmileage` 
  FROM `foo` 
  JOIN (SELECT `id`, MAX(`date`) AS `latestreading` FROM `foo` GROUP BY `id`) 
  AS `baz` 
  ON `foo`.`id` = `baz`.`id`
  AND `foo`.`date` = `baz`.`latestreading`
 ) 
AS `currentmileages`
JOIN
 (SELECT `foo`.`id`, `mileage` AS `previousmileage` 
  FROM `foo` 
  JOIN `past_month_readings` 
  ON `foo`.`id`=`past_month_readings`.`id` 
  AND `foo`.`date` = `past_month_readings`.`latestreading`)
AS `previousmileages`
ON
`currentmileages`.`id` = `previousmileages`.`id`
```

For

```
+------+------------+---------+
| id   | date       | mileage |
+------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 2015-06-15 |    1234 |
|    1 | 2015-07-15 |    1444 |
|    1 | 2015-07-25 |    2000 |
|    2 | 2015-06-01 |     100 |
|    2 | 2015-06-20 |     200 |
|    2 | 2015-07-20 |     300 |
+------+------------+---------+
```

this results in

```
+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | `currentmileage`-`previousmileage` |
+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 |                                766 |
|    2 |                                100 |
+------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Looks like I solved it with the following code:

```
SELECT Main.vehicle_id, Main.latestreading as currentmileage, Link.latestReadin as previousmilage 
FROM (SELECT m1.*, max(l1.rowid) as LinkID
FROM `foo` as m1
JOIN `foo` as l1
ON l1.vehicle_id= m1.vehicle_id
WHERE l1.date< m1.date
GROUP BY m1.rowid
ORDER BY m1.rowid desc) as Main
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `foo`) as Link
ON Link.rowid = Main.LinkID
```